# Form ajax group label and value on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Hi I have a form with 3 input text fields that has the same attribute (name="product").

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <label for="product1" id="product1" class="required">Product 1</label>
    <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="product1"  name="product" required>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <label for="product2" id="product2" class="required">Product 2</label>
    <input  type="text" class="form-control " id="product2"  name="product" required>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <label for="product3" id="product3" class="required">Product 3</label>
    <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="product3"  name="product" required>
</div>
```

When i submit i want to take the values of all of the inputs  with the name product and send them in this format

```
Label name  value | Label name : value | Label name : value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submit run a loop and build your array.

For example:

```
var arr = [];

$(form).find('input[name="product"]').each(function(index,element){

arr.push({ 'label': $(element).parent().find('label').text(), 'value':$(element).val() }); 

});
```